# How do i remove NULL input in C?

Tags: c, loops, null

My teacher has asked me to "Fool proof" my code from any sort of misuse, So I have come up with an
program that can remove any empty values (by disallowing them entirely)

Here is the Un-foolproofed code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char text[16];

    printf("Type something: "); 
    fgets(text,16, stdin);
    printf("You typed: %s",text);

    getch();
}
```

I have made some simple adjustments to ensure there is no error, however, i cannot get the if  filter to work properly, as it still allows the NULL input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char text[16];
    int loop;
    do
    {
        printf("Type something: "); 
        fgets(text,16, stdin);

        if( text[0] == '\0')
        {
            printf("Try again");
            system("cls");
            loop=1;
        }
        else
        {
            loop = -1;
        }
    }
    while(loop > 0);
    printf("You typed: %s",text);

    getch();
}
```

I've tried google and i cannot get a solid answer, this probably is some very simple line of code, but sadly i have no idea what it is.

Edit: it's fixed, the if statement should be:

if (text[0] == '\n')

Comment: Have you considered checking the return of `fgets`?

Comment: The text read by fgets is always twerminated by `\n`, thus `text[0]` won't be `'\0'` but `'\n'`.

Comment: Read some documentation on what `fgets` does.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Unless it isn't.

Comment: I was told fgets is just a better subsitute for scanf

Comment: @MichaelWalz `text[0]` is _not_ always terminated by `'\n'`.  1) The last line of input may end without a `'\n'`. 2) If a preceding `char ` is `'\0'`, the  `'\n'` and additional terminating `'\0'` will be there, but code typically uses `strlen()` to find the length and that will stop on the earlier `'\0'`.  3) If there is an I/0 error, the contents of `text` is not defined, so `'\n'` may not exist 4) if the size of the buffer is 1 or less. 5) When EOF is detected and NULL returned, the contents `text` are not changed and may not have a `'\n'` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the return value from `fgets()` is the best first step to fool-proofing user I/O.

```
char text[16];
printf("Type something: "); 

if (fgets(text, sizeof text, stdin) == NULL) {
  if (feof(stdin)) Handle_stdin_is_closed();  // no more input
  if (ferror(stdin) Handle_IOerror():  // very rare event, more common with files
}

// Test is input is is only a '\n'
if (text[0] == '\n') 
   printf("Try again");  

// Look for long line. 
size_t len = strlen(text);
if (len + 1 == sizeof text && text[len - 2] != '\n') HandleLongLine();
```

The next step is to look for scan errors.  Let's assume code is to read a `long`.

```
errno = 0;
char *endptr;
long = strtol(text, &endptr, 10);
if (errno) Handle_NumericOverflow();
if (text == endptr) Handle_InputIsNotNumeric();
while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) endptr++;
if (*endptr != '\0') Handle_ExtraTextAfterNumber();
```

Although this is a lot of code, robust handling of hostle user input is best spun off to a helper function where lots of tests can be had.

```
char * prompt = "Type something: ";
long number;
int stat = GetLong(stdin, prompt, &number);  // put all tests in here.
if (stat > 0) Handle_SomeFailure();
if (stat < 0) Handle_EOF();
printf("%ld\n", number);
```

Comment: It works, thank you sir, wait you edited it... I literally just subbed in the if (text[0] == '\n') line

Comment: @It'sRainingMen  There are many ways an evil user will attempt to break code, let alone some user typing in random stuff.  To catch them all is difficult.  I do not try to put all these tests throughout code, but in a helper function that I can improve as new vulnerabilities are identified.

Comment: I'll be honest, i have no idea what the rest of the code is trying to stop, is it for non alphabetical characters?

Comment: Long line: "12345678901234567890\n" will read in only the 1st 15 and `text` is 16 long.  What do do with the rest? Overflow: "1234567890123\n", and `long` may only handle up to 2147483647.  `text == endptr)` detects input of "x".  `if (*endptr != '\0')` detects "123 456".

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` reads a whole line including the newline into the buffer and 0-terminates it.

If it reads something and then the stream ends, the read line will not have a newline.
If the line does not fit, it won't contain a newline.
If an error occurs before it successfully reads the first character, it returns `NULL`.

Please read the man-page for `fgets`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html

Comment: *"If the line is too long, it won't be 0-terminated."* Not so, 7.21.7.2p2: *"The fgets function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array."*

Comment: @user694733: Sry, meant newline there. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `fgets()` man page

```
char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);

//fgets() returns s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file
//occurs while no characters have been read.
```

so, you can check the return value of `fgets()`

```
n = fgets(text,16, stdin);
```

if that value is `NULL`, then nothing have been read.

you can do this by checking the value of `n` in a for loop,

```
if( n == NULL)
{
    printf("Try again");
    system("cls");
    loop=1;
}
else
{
    loop = -1;
}
```

Comment: How does this work in my program?, trying to write in the variable n isn't working

Comment: @It'sRainingMen: how are you coding this??

Comment: In C on DEV C++. i have no idea what i'm supposed to be writing with all these errors

Comment: @It'sRainingMen: if the errors are too many to be asked in a comment.. ask in another question.. or post here

Comment: Ok, in your answer, what do i do in my program?

Comment: @harris Ok, when i try to declare n as a variable it has an error, and when i try to use n = fgets(....) another error

Comment: n = fgets(..) , n is undeclared. using int or char n to declare doesn't work either

Comment: @It'sRainingMen: have you declared n in the beginning? like

`int n;`

Comment: @harris that's the error , int n; it says something about a pointer and a cast

Comment: @It'sRainingMen: sorry, my mistake.. declare `n` as a char pointer

`char* n;`